# Properties of max of many linear combinations of a multivariate normal vector and/or sum of top $k$ elements of a multivariate normal vector

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics

Thank you in advance for your help!

I am interested in studying the following probability:
$$P\big[\max_{H \subset X,|H|=k} \sum_{i \in H} \mathbf{a}_i^T \mathbf{w} \ge 0 \big],$$
where $\mathbf{a}_i$ is a fixed vector, $\mathbf{w}$ is a multivariate normal vector (for simplcity, we can even assume that the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{w}$ is a diagonal matrix), $X$ is a fixed set of $N$ elements.

There are two ways I am thinking about right now to proceed my analysis:

First, we can see that $$\max_{H \subset X,|H|=k} \sum_{i \in H} \mathbf{a}_i^T \mathbf{w}=\max\{\mathbf{C}_1^T \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{C}_2^T \mathbf{w},\ldots,\mathbf{C}_{{N\choose k}}^T \mathbf{w}\}.$$
So our focus now is to study the maximum of many linear combinations of a normal random vector.

Second, we can see that
$$\max_{H \subset X,|H|=k} \sum_{i \in H} \mathbf{a}_i^T \mathbf{w}=\sum_{i=N-k-1}^N \mathbf{W}_{(i)},$$
where $\mathbf{W}_{i}=\mathbf{a}_i^T \mathbf{w}$, and $\mathbf{W}_{(i)}$ is the $i$-th order statistics of $\{\mathbf{W}_{i}\}$. So our focus in this case is to study the sum of top $k$ order statistics of many linear combinations of a normal random vector.

Any advice on either of the way mentioned above is really appreciated. Thank you so much!